# Spring OAuth2 - CustomAuthenticationProvider login issue

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I have setup an Authorization and Resource Server to be consumed by a web application (all done in Spring MVC 4.3.9), but have a problem with the requests done with OAuth2RestTemplate and a **custom AuthenticationProvider** set on the Authorization Server.

At first request (when the user logins), I set the username and password of the autowired OAuth2RestTemplate (**I'm using password grant**), and send the request to an URL of the API, like:

```
@Autowired
OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

..

public <T> T postEntityNoAuth(String restMethod, Credentials credentials, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> resultType) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // set your entity to send
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(credentials, headers);

        restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest().set("username", credentials.getUsername());
        restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest().set("password", credentials.getPassword());
        ResponseEntity<T> restResult = restTemplate.exchange(authServerURL + restMethod, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                resultType);

        OAuth2AccessToken token = restTemplate.getAccessToken();

        return restResult.getBody();
    }
```

Everything is fine, I get an access token, because the authentication was successful, which was done in the auth server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);

    }

//more code
```

The custom authentication provider validates against a LDAP search, as I don't have an UserDetailsService (**I don't have permission to read user details from the LDAP server**, only authenticate with user and pwd).

The thing is that **after login**, when I do other requests with the autowired OAuth2RestTemplate, the provider authenticate method is called again , and given that I don't have the credentials anymore (which in this case shouldn't be needed as I have an access token, and I checked that is the one assigned at login), it returns 401 Unauthorized.

The question is, how can I validate against the access token and user id, or how to skip the validation in the custom provider, given that I don't need to authenticate anymore? For the following requests, only the access token should be used, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended getting the access token from the OAuth2RestTemplate at first login, and then get the access token so I pass it as a parameter for a normal RestTemplate (as ?access_token=...). When the access token expires, the OAuth2RestTemplate gets another one automatically via the refresh token (for this, you have to set the grant "refresh_token" for the same client). If the refresh token expires, then is time to login again and the cycle repeats.